# Select where type command for Matlab structure

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a 2x3 Matlab structure containing the following fields:

`projectname`, `projectcategory` and `projectcost`.

Here is a loop that goes through the contents of the structure:

```
>> for i=1:3
projectstructure(i).projectname
projectstructure(i).projectcategory
projectstructure(i).projectcost
end
ans =    
project1    
ans =  
category1    
ans =   
50000   
ans = 
project2      
ans =    
category2    
ans =    
25000    
ans =    
project3    
ans =    
category1    
ans =   
65000    
>>
```

I would like to see if, in Matlab, there is an efficient way to "query" this structure based on the `projectname` field. I.e. whether there is a programmatic way to say extract the `projectcategory` field value for, say, `projectname3`.

This is similar to an excel `VLOOKUP` function or MySQL `SELECT FROM WHERE` type thing. I would like to see if Matlab can do this without having to resort to large (and costly) database extensions like the database toolbox.

Comment: I think it may be possible, but your wording and variables are a bit unclear. Can you give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
projectstructure(strcmp({projectstructure.projectname}, 'project3')).projectcategory
```

**Explanation**

- `{projectstructure.projectname}`: create a cell array of all project names
- `strcmp({projectstructure.projectname}, 'project3')`: compares all the names with the desired one
- `projectstructure(strcmp({projectstructure.projectname}, 'project3'))`: select the desired project using [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)